# What is the correct attitude towards orange soda?

Tags: segulah

Orange soda, specifically Fanta, was invented by a German Coca Cola factory during WWII. They were unable to obtain cola nut extract and could no longer produce Coca Cola. They decided to make a soda out of whatever they could access: color, aspartame, and a flavor that wasn't exactly orange.

Should Jews avoid Fanta as a drink for Nazis? Or should we dafka drink it as a segula in commemoration of the downfall of our enemies?

Comment: Option 3: doesn't matter at all.

Comment: You make the erroneous claim that Fanta was invented "as a drink for the Nazis". It was invented by a German factory during WWII for the German people as a whole.

Comment: Nothing to do with Judaism.

Comment: Why is this tagged *segulah*?

Comment: ... And VWs also...

Answer (score 1):

I would say, we should learn from our Sages in the times of the destruction of the second Temple by the Romans.

I can't judge what catastrophe was more devastating, but still, both were very painful for the Jewish nation.

They could boycott anything Roman but they didn't. We could probably learn from them.

---

<sub>From "Chassidisher" POV, there's an עניין to use the Goyish products דווקא, especially in גלות, as it stems from the Posuk "ואכלת עמים רבים", which hints on נצוצות of Kedushah that had fallen onto them and by consuming them we bring them to the Kedushah.</sub>

Comment: There were 4-6 generations of Sages in Eretz Israel from R' Yochonon Ben Zakkay to Hillel II. They did not mention anything AFAIK. Babylonian Sages were long after and still, they mention "לא נאכל בשר ולא נשתה יין", but nothing about the Romans.

Comment: Don't be ridiculous, the Sages could boycott a lot of things and they didn't, not just about "buying products". We do not מחדשים גזרות the Sages didn't rule.